# pass param to parent layout in nextjs13

Tags: next.js13

I want to conditionally render the parent layout based on the children props.

parent layout

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Breadcrumb from '@/components/ui/breadcrumb'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Breadcrumb/>
      {children}

    </>
  )
}
```

the conditions that i want add

```
breadcrumb && <Breadcrumb/>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed issue with conditional rendering

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Breadcrumb from '@/components/ui/breadcrumb'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  // Defines conditions based on the breadcrumb prop
  const shouldRenderBreadcrumb = /* Define conditions based on the breadcrumb prop */;

  return (
    <>
      {shouldRenderBreadcrumb && <Breadcrumb />}
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```